# Receiving Argument #2 should be an array in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I banged my head against the walls for 2 days now and I can't seem to shake this error.

I am receiving this error:

```
ErrorException (E_WARNING)
array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array
```

What I am trying to do: Each user can have a list of urls in the database. The same url can be in two or more user account, so it is a many to many relationship.

My **UrlsController** looks like this:

```
<?php

 namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use App\User;
   use App\Urls;
    use Illuminate\Http\Request;
     use Auth;

 class UrlsController extends Controller
  {

public function __construct() {
    $this->middleware('auth');
}

public function index(User $user)
{
    return view('editurl', compact('user'));
}

public function store(User $user) {

    $user_id = Auth::user()->id;

    $data = request()->validate([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'url' => 'required',
    ]);

    auth()->user()->userurls()->create([
        'user_id' => $data['user_id'],
        'url' => $data['url'],
    ]);

    return redirect("/url/" . auth()->user()->id);

}

}
```

My **Urls** model looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Urls extends Model
{
    //protected $quarded = [];
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','url'];

    protected $table = 'userUrls';

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class);
    }

}
```

My **blade** file looks like this:

```
    @extends('layouts.pagprincipala')

@section('content')


<section id="home" class="home pt-5 pb-5">

    <div class="container mb-5">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <h1 class="h4">Adaugare url-uri</h1>
                <hr class="bg-dark w-25 ml-0">
                <p>
                    <form action="/url/{{$user->id}}" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
                    @csrf

                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-8 offset-2">

                                <div class="form-group row">

                                    <label for="url" class="col-md-12 col-form-label">Adaugare URL (doar emag si pcgarage)</label>
                                    <input id="url"
                                    type="text" 
                                    class="form-control{{$errors->has('url') ? 'is-invalid' : ''}}" 
                                    name="url" 
                                    autocomplete="url" autofocus>

                                    @if($errors->has('url'))
                                        <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                            <strong class="text-danger">Campul url este obligatoriu.</strong>
                                        </span>
                                    @endif

                                </div>

                                <div class="row pt-4">

                                    <button class="btn btn-primary">Adaugare URL</button>

                                </div>

                            </div>
                        </div>

                    </form>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

  </section>


@endsection
```

Also, my routes look like this:

```
Route::get('/url/{user}', 'UrlsController@index')->name('editurl');
Route::post('/url/{user}', 'UrlsController@store')->name('updateurl');
```

Can you give me a suggestion on how to move forward from this ?!

Comment: Does the error message point to a file and a line number? It seems like it would be some laravel function calling `array_map()` under the hood and it's not getting what it is expecting.

Comment: Hello, I am sorry for not posting this, it points to this file: C:\wamp64\www\infopret\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Validation\ValidationRuleParser.php to line 92 which is: return array_map([$this, 'prepareRule'], $rule);  The function itself is: protected function explodeExplicitRule($rule)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in your validator:

```
$data = request()->validate([
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'url' => 'required',
    ]);
```

You try to validate the user_id with a rule that **is** the user id. What you probably want to achieve is `'user_id' => 'integer',` or you can drop this rule all together as you know who the user is because of `Auth()->user()`. This should do:

```
$data = request()->validate([
        'url' => 'required|url', //checks if it is an URL
    ]);
```

What we don't know is how your `User` model is constructed. With a many to many you need a pivot table `urls_users` or `user_urls_users` with `url_id` and `user_id` which means you don't need a `user_id` in the `userUrls` table, just id and url. But that's another issue. If you want to make sure any user has any url only once, you can use [the `->sync()` methode](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships).

Comment: Hello Dimitri, your comments helped a lot. Besides the validation which you were right, I had the pivot table, but I had the mistake of adding the user id into the userUrls table as well, after making the changes, everything works as it should.

Comment: Nice to hear. Happy coding @FBK